# Why won't Google App Engine find my module (Python 3)?

Tags: python, google-app-engine

I'm new to Google App Engine and having the trouble that the app doesn't find my module. I get the error `line 5, in <module> import foo as bar ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'foo'`. I have the current file structure as seen below (following a great [tutorial for Flask](https://blog.miguelgrinberg.com/post/the-flask-mega-tutorial-part-i-hello-world)).

The problem is that `routes.py` cannot import `foo.py`.

- app engine:/

  - app

    - static/css
    - templates
    - __init__.py
    - **foo.py**
    - **routes.py**
  - app.yaml
  - config.py
  - main.py
  - requirements.txt
  - source-context.json

Why is this? Are there special requirements for how files are structured on App Engine as this works locally?

Also, just to have things working I've tried having the code in the module foo in routes instead and the code works. But the code doesn't belong there and I want to structure it better but the app breaks when separating. In the end I would like to add directory "app engine":/app/libs (or else on recomendation) where I store my custom stuff.

**EDIT** (add code sample from routes.py)

```
from flask import render_template, flash, redirect, url_for
from app import app
from app.forms import LookupForm
import logging
import foo as bar

@app.route("/")
@app.route("/index")

def index():
    return render_template("index.html")
```

Comment: Could you add a minimal code sample displaying how you are performing the import?

Comment: @DenisT. Added top of code from routes.py.

Comment: @Nelumbo I would suggest you to follow GCP structure of an app project : 

https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/getting-started/python-standard-env

Comment: @Nelumbo Also you can refer how to structure your web service files: 
https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python3/building-app/writing-web-service

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was able to reproduce the error you are experiencing. Here are my observations:

- You are storing the **foo** module in a local folder called 'app' (a sub-directory of where you have your **main.py** file).
- In order to reference the module in this situation, you would need to include the name of the **sub-directory** when doing the import.

---

Change the following line in your **routes.py** file:

```
import foo as bar
```

to:

```
import app.foo as bar
```

I have tested this solution and it worked for me. Please let me know if it helps.

Comment: That worked, thanks! So the reference for the module needs to be from **main.py** and not from the actual script/module using the module?

Comment: Yes, use the **absolute import** *(considering that the 'app engine/' directory is the root directory of your app)* to reference the local dependencies - [link](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/patterns/packages/). You will also see that the absolute import is used (e.g. `from app.<local-dependency> import ...`) in the [tutorial](https://blog.miguelgrinberg.com/post/the-flask-mega-tutorial-part-i-hello-world) you linked, starting from chapter 3.